# If $X$ is lognormally distributed, what is the distribution of $1/X$?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, normalization, normality-assumption, lognormal-distribution

Let $X$ be lognormal with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (such that log($X$) is Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and $\sigma$).

What is the distribution of $1/X$? (I.e., its "simple" parametric distribution)?

Comment: Since $\log(1/x)=-\log(x)$ what does this tell you..?!

Comment: That it has same mean (different sign) and same variance! thanks

Comment: No it should tell you much more.

Comment: @Jorge If $\log(X)$ is normal, what's the *distribution* of its negative, $-\log(X)$?

Comment: its also normal but with mean with opposite sign and same variance right? That's what I meant above. What is the "much more" that @Xi'an might have been thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

Almost answered in comments, so just to finish it off: suppose $Y$ has a normal distribution $Y \sim \text{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Then $X=e^Y$ has a lognormal distribution, and $\frac1{X}=\frac1{e^Y}=e^{-Y}$ also has a lognormal distribution with parameters (of the underlying normal) $-\mu, \sigma^2$.